# How I can convert class instance to string when using new?

Tags: javascript

I need to achieve the following behavior:
So when creating a class instance via `new`, I received a string, not a class object. How to implement this? Is it even possible?

**For example**

```
class ExampleClass{
  constructor(str) {
    this.str = str;
  }
     // some code I guess...
}

const str = new ExampleClass('example')

console.log(str) // 'example'
```

Comment: Huh? Do you want `str` to be a string value, not an `ExampleClass`? Or do you just want `console.log(str)` to output the string passed to the constructor?

Comment: The latter can be achieved by providing an implementation for `toString()` that returns that value.

Comment: I want the created objects placed in an array using the join (' ') method to be concatenated into a string.

Comment: Now, I get this [object Object][object Object][object Object] and this not wonder, but how I can  achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```js
class ExampleClass extends String {}
```

Comment: No, I can't extends another class

Comment: In that case, you can define `valueOf()` or `toString()` method in your class.

Comment: hm, yep, Its worked, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

While using Class with new it create **this** instance internally and return it

HOW IT WORK INTERNALLY

```
let ExampleClass = function(_str){
  //this = Object.create(ExampleClass.prototype);
  this.str = _str
  // return this;
}
str = new ExampleClass('EXAMPLE');
```

Good practice: Can create helper function or getters instead of changing implementation

```
class ExampleClass{
  constructor(str) {
    this._str = str;
  }
  // some code...
  get str(){return this._str;}
  set str(str){this._str = str;}
  helperFetchStr(){ return this._str;}
}
new ExampleClass('EXAMPLE1').str;
new ExampleClass('EXAMPLE2').helperFetchStr();
```

Extending the String class. Here prototype will be from string enabling you to perform all string operations directly on str

let similar = new String("EXAMPLE")

```
class ExampleClass extends String {
  constructor(str) {
    super(str);
  }
  // some code...
}
const str = new ExampleClass('EXAMPLE');
//console.log(str.{STRING_OPERATIONS})
```